# Sum last 3 columns in Excel using macros

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel File, I need to find out the last 3 columns since because my column length gets updated each month when new data comes and need to do a sum on that last 3 columns values as I want recent data and put the sum in the new column.

EG:

```
A B C D   
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 2
```

In the existing sheet, I want to find B, C, D as recent 3 columns (last 3 columns) and sum it up and put in new column E.

```
A B C D E 
1 2 3 4 9 
5 6 7 8 21 
1 2 3 2 7
```

Please help me with ways to automate it with Excel macros. Thanks in advance for your help. I created a code but it's not working

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
End With
MsgBox LastCol
Dim LastRow As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox LastRow
Dim j As Integer
For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = LastCol - 2 To LastCol
        Range(i & LastCol + 1).Value = Range(i & j).Value + Range(i & j + 1).Value + Range(i & j + 2).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Hint: find the last row, and last column. Then loop through the rows (until last row), for each row, sum the last column with the previous 2 columns, and there you go.

Comment: My first question is why no formula, that would be much easier, even using a formula and converting it to values would be easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shai Rado. I will incorporate this idea and will post once if any issue comes up.

Comment: You want sum of last 3 columns or what ? Your question heading and details are different.

Comment: Hi Peh, i am wondering what formula i have to use here, i tried using INDEX() but its not working

Comment: should not column e be 9 21 and 7?

Comment: You don't need those with statements, also dim your variables all up the top, also use long not integer. `Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, j As Long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks a lot for your precious time to reply.** 
      I have found a solution in Excel VBA macro and it works very fine!!

```
 Dim start As Integer
 Dim Mid As Integer
 Dim finish As Integer

 start = LastCol - 2
 Mid = LastCol - 1
 finish = LastCol

 For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = start To LastCol
      If Not IsEmpty(Range("D" & i).Value) Then
          Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(i, start).Address & ":" & Cells(i, finish).Address & ")"
      End If
   Next j
 Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in E1

```
=SUM(OFFSET(E1,0,-3,1,3))
```

to get the sum of the 3 columns before column E.
Any time you insert new columns before E it will adjust automatically to the last 3 columns right before the sum column.

For more information have a look at [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66).

Comment: equivalent but uglier is: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-3))+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2))+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))

Comment: @JeremyKahan Why would someone use 3 volatile functions if you can do it with one? There is always a way to make things uglier.

Comment: @msstdy please don't post code as comments. That's just unreadable. If you want to post an answer use the answer button. Otherwise edit your original question to add code.

Comment: @peh I said it was ugllier. It is just how I thought of it. That is why I did not post it as a separate answer. Yours is better.

Comment: @peh it gives whole sum of 3 columns together. How should i apply this formula in the cell

Comment: @msstdy I don't understand. You need to be much more specific please. *If your question is too long for a comment please edit your original question and add an example.*

Answer (score 0):

**Use Arrays** , Whenever you have to work with multiple cells,rows or columns. Use Arrays. First you hold the value in array and work with the array in memory.
Try to minimize the interaction with the Workbook/Worksheet/sheets.

It will make you code less slow and less error prone.

Here is the code for your reference :

```
Function getsum()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tot_row As Long
Dim row_to_start As Long
Dim cl As Long
Dim irow As Long

Dim sumarr As Variant ' Declare the array

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    sumarr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Put the current region in the array
    tot_row = UBound(sumarr, 2) 'Get total rows
    row_to_start = tot_row - 2 ' Get the rows from where sum process with start


    For cl = row_to_start To UBound(sumarr, 2) ' start from 3rd last column till last column
        For irow = LBound(sumarr) + 1 To UBound(sumarr) ' from second row to the last row
            msum = msum + sumarr(irow, cl) ' do the sum
        Next irow
    Next cl
getsum = msum ' return the sum

End Function
```